# How to construct email for outlook in javascript

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, nodemailer

I'm using node *nodemailer* to send email from my web app. Using node2html plug-in to convert JSON object to HTML.

I have a table in the HTML email and it works fine in Gmail (renders correctly) but the same is not working in outlook. The table in the email shows like following - as you can see it is not formatting at all.

Researched online and StackOverflow and while found number of references all suggesting not using external CSS references and in-lining CSS and as you can see below I'm not using any CSS - it is just table, th, tr and td tags but still outlook would not render this correctly. I'm using outlook 2016.

Any pointers appreciated.

```
<html><head></head><body><table><tbody><tr><th>Company</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>Island Trading</td><td>Helen Bennett</td><td>UK</td></tr><tr><td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td><td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td><td>Canada</td></tr><tr><td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td><td>Giovanni Rovelli</td><td>Italy</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```

Comment: Yes you cannot use external css stylesheets for outlook emails. All styles have to be inline also not all html tags are supported tables, videos, and images are however the video and images has to be either hosted on a server or base 64 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Zurb Foundation for Email is built on Node and uses Gulp to build emails. This sound like the best place for you to start considering what you are attempting to do. It features node modules which can automatically inline email, saving you the need to do so.

- http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html
- http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/sass-guide.html

95% of emails could be run by a external style sheet, but sadly, Outlook 2016 isn't really one of them and one of the worst for email compliance. I wanted to add that Gmail does not work with external style sheets, which means it doesn't work with Google fonts either.

I hope that gives you a direction.

Good luck.